# My javascript/html and node.js logic are on separate servers - can they interact securely?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, security, websocket

Server A is a standard apache/php webserver. It delivers HTML/Javascript to a browser, which connects to Server B (a node.js server) using websockets.

It looks like this: Server A (http request->) Browser (websockets->) Server B

**Is there a way to verify on Server B that Server A is the source of a request?**

My understanding is that HTTP referer can be easily spoofed. I thought about having PHP fetch a one-time use token to allow the javascript code to prove it's identity, but hacking it would be as simple as loading up the genuine page with javascript disabled and extracting the token.

This really isn't an area of expertise for me, so I'd appreciate any advice - thanks! :)

Comment: Just to confirm, server A connects to Server B - which server does the user connect to?

Comment: Pre-shared secrets, encryption, digital signatures & public/private keys, there are lots of ways to protect the channel when it's point to point. The two servers may need to communicate with each other directly or a trusted 3rd party to establish trust. If there's a client in the middle that can manipulate the requests in some "hacking" way though, then things are far more complex. If you protect the payload and it's tamper proof, then it doesn't matter what the client does (other than they can choose to not send something).

Comment: @ZackNewsham - sorry, I wasn't clear. Server A serves an HTML/Javascript page to the user, which then connects to Server B through websockets. I want to verify that Server A was the source of a request on Server B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've never done this with JS, however it works quite nicely with a central authentication system:

1) User connects to server A and authenticates (password for example)

2) Server A then sends a message to server B saying "user X connected from address Y at time Z"

3) Server B then saves this information to a database and returns a unique code to server A

4) Server A in turn returns it to the user.

5) The user then passes this unique code to server B in the request, along with their username.

6) Server B checks that this user connected with server A from that address within the last X minutes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! :) I'm sorry if I'm not being as clear as I could be --

The problem doesn't involve authenticating a user - I'm trying to authenticate the source of a request. I'm looking for a way to confirm that a request on Server B came from a page served by Server A - whether or not a user has logged in.

Comment: Ok, the result is the same - just skip the "authenticates" part. When a user requests a page from server A, tell server B to expect a request. Then, when the user connects to server B, they have to provide the number that B provided A, each number is tied to a specific IP address, and each number can be used only once (optional) and only for a specific period of time (also optional)